# Ambigious mongoDB query, matches everything

Tags: mongodb-query

Why does this term match everything:

```
{result: $and[{$exists:true}, {$ne: 0}]}
{result:{$exists:true}, result:{$ne:0}} (this too as suggested)
```

The idea was to match fields, which have a key "result" and are where result is not equal zero. Why this does match a document, which only has a oid?

**edit:**

What works as expected is the following:

```
{ $and: [ { result:{$exists:true}}, {result:{$ne: 0}}]}
```

The question is still the same, **why** do those queries behaive like this?

Comment: This one, not working {result: $and[{$exists:true}, {$ne: 0}]}, it give an error. On my suggestion the filters are executed independently of the other. Filter result:{$ne:0}, is true, because result doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

try:
{result:{$exists:true}, result:{$ne:0}}

Comment: you try it.^^ This was my first guess. shows you everything.

Comment: Can you give some example documents?

Comment: {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f50b9ccbf48ae17149468a5"
    }
}